# AngularJS : Recursive tree style

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

as the name suggests i am trying to build a recursive tree directive I has to mimic the structure from the [expression builder](http://expbuilder.googlecode.com/hg/src/cb/condition-builder.html) as that's how its been setup and i want to replace it with an angular component. I have had a look at the other posts on the forum but mine is not exactly the same.

the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cerebral86/3aHAp/) thanks to julien for showing me how to fix it.

the model which is based off the expression builder has a structure like a condition object inside a field then an expression array and then another array which will be called nested expression but essentially will contain a condition object and this can be nested as deep as it wants to go.

Anyway so i created a directive to create a list entry for each entry in the expression builder (ng-repeat) then i created a link function to find out when its at the last loop and after that repeat the loop for every item in the nested expression array (there must be a better way to do this).

It works for the nestings but now i want to assign a button at each root level ul so that you add a new entry(expression) to the array another but when i try it seems to duplicate the array and then attach the new value.

The other tasks is to: 
And a root level button so that you can add a second nested expression array (i,e, two ul's at the same level) , a root level delete so that you can delete a whole ul nesting and a delete at each li so that you can delete just one expression.

I will keep at the fiddle but maybe someone can solve it before i can get the fiddle working.

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Regards

```
angular.module("expressionBuilderApp", [])
.controller('ExpressionBuilderController', ['$scope', function($scope) {  
    $scope.conditions = {
                operator : "and",
                expressions : [
                    {
                        name : "moo"
                    },
                    {
                        name : "mooest"
                    },
                    {
                        name : "mooster"
                    }
                ],
                nestedexpressions : [   
                    {       
                        operator : "or",
                        expressions : [
                            {
                                name : "bow wow"
                            },
                            {
                                name : "woof woof"
                            }
                        ],
                        nestedexpressions : [
                            {
                                operator : "or",
                                expressions : [
                                    {
                                        name : "meow"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        name : "meeew"
                                    }
                                ],
                                nestedexpressions : [
                                    {
                                        operator : "And",
                                        expressions : [
                                            {
                                                name : "oink"
                                            },
                                            {
                                                name : "squeel"
                                            }
                                        ],
                                        nestedexpressions :
                                        [

                                        ]
                                    },
                                    {
                                        operator : "Or",
                                        expressions : [
                                            {
                                                name : "hoot hoot"
                                            },
                                            {
                                                name : "stares with yellow eyes"
                                            }
                                        ],
                                        nestedexpressions :
                                        [

                                        ]
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]               
        };
 }])
.directive('expressionBuilder', function(){
    return  {
        restrict: 'E',
        template : '<ul><button ng-click="addNewCondition(conditions.expressions)">add</button><li nested-expressions="" conditions="conditions.nestedexpressions" ng-repeat="expression in conditions.expressions" >{{expression.name}}</li></ul>',
        replace: true,
        scope: {conditions: "="},
        controller: function($scope){
            $scope.addNewCondition = function(arrayToPushInto){
                var newCondition = {name: "testing"};
                arrayToPushInto.push(newCondition);
            }
        }
    }
})
.directive('nestedExpressions', function($compile) {
  return {  
        restrict: 'A',
        replace: true,
        link: function(scope, element, attrs){  
            if (scope.$last){
                var conditions = scope.conditions;
                console.log(conditions) ;           
                if(conditions.nestedexpressions.length > 0){
                    element.after($compile('<li ng-repeat="nestedexpression in conditions.nestedexpressions"><expression-builder conditions="nestedexpression"></expression-builder></li>')(scope));
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: You forgot to declare your application in the HTML of yyour fiddle & you must include Angular not "on load" but "No wrap - in <head>". See: http://jsfiddle.net/86SZE/

Comment: you awesome brother. Thanks. So now that that's working do you see my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why to be honest but i based my code of [this](http://jsfiddle.net/brendanowen/uXbn6/8/) so thanks buddy whoever you are.

Ng-include seems to just use the scope of the array passed in and does not duplicate the functions through directive nesting see the [fiddle] (http://jsfiddle.net/cerebral86/g62KP/5/)

Hopefully this helps someone else.

```
<script type="text/ng-template"  id="conditionExpressionBuilder.html">
    <div>
    <div>
        <button ng-click="addNestedCondition(conditions.nestedexpressions)">Add ()</button>
        <button ng-click="addNewCondition(conditions.expressions)">Add node</button>
    </div>
    <div>
        <select>
            <option ng-selected="{{conditions.operator == operator.value}}" ng-repeat="operator in operators" value="{{operator.value}}">{{operator.display}}</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div>
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="expression in conditions.expressions">
                <div>
                    <span>
                        <button ng-click="delete(expression, conditions.expressions)" ng-disabled="$first">Delete Item</button>
                    </span>
                    <span>
                        <select>
                            <option ng-selected="{{filterfield.value == expression.filterField}}" ng-repeat="filterfield in filterfields" value="{{filterfield.value}}">{{filterfield.display}}</option>
                        </select>
                    </span>
                    <span>
                        <select>
                            <option ng-selected="{{comparator.value == expression.comparator}}" ng-repeat="comparator in comparators" value="{{comparator.value}}">{{comparator.display}}</option>
                        </select>
                    </span>
                    <span><input type="text" value="{{expression.expressionValue}}" /></span>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li ng-repeat="conditions in conditions.nestedexpressions" ng-if="conditions.expressions.length > 0">
                <button ng-click="removeNestedCondition($index, $parent.$parent.conditions.nestedexpressions)">Remove ()</button>
                <ng-include src="'conditionExpressionBuilder.html'"></ng-include>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
</script>
```

```
angular.module("expressionBuilderApp", [])
.controller('expressionBuilderController', ['$scope', function($scope) {  
         $scope.operators = [
            {
                display: "And",
                value: "and"
            },
            {
                display: "Or",
                value: "or"
            }
        ];
        $scope.filterFields = [
                  {
                      display: "Code",
                      value: "code"
                  },
                  {
                      display: "Capital",
                      value: "capital"
                  },
                  {
                      display: "Government",
                      value: "government"
                  },
                  {
                      display: "Population",
                      value: "population"
                  }
        ];
        $scope.comparators = [
                {
                    display: "contains",
                    value: "contains"
                },
                {
                    display: "Starts With",
                    value: "startswith"
                },
                {
                    display: "Ends With",
                    value: "endswith"
                },
                {
                    display: "Doest not Contain",
                    value: "doesnotcontain"
                }
        ];
        $scope.conditions = {
            operator: "and",
            expressions: [
                {
                    filterField: "code",
                    comparator: "contains",
                    expressionValue: "moo"
                },
                {
                    filterField: "capital",
                    comparator: "startswith",
                    expressionValue: "mooest"
                },
                {
                    filterField: "government",
                    comparator: "endswith",
                    expressionValue: "mooster"
                }
            ],
            nestedexpressions: [
                {
                    operator: "or",
                    expressions: [
                        {
                            filterField: "code",
                            comparator: "endswith",
                            expressionValue: "bow wow"
                        },
                        {
                            filterField: "government",
                            comparator: "doesnotcontain",
                            expressionValue: "woof woof"
                        }
                    ],
                    nestedexpressions: [
                        {
                            operator: "or",
                            expressions: [
                                {
                                    filterField: "code",
                                    comparator: "contains",
                                    expressionValue: "meow"
                                },
                                {
                                    filterField: "code",
                                    comparator: "contains",
                                    expressionValue: "meeew"
                                }
                            ],
                            nestedexpressions: [
                                {
                                    operator: "And",
                                    expressions: [
                                        {
                                            filterField: "government",
                                            comparator: "doesnotcontain",
                                            expressionValue: "oink"
                                        },
                                        {
                                            filterField: "code",
                                            comparator: "endswith",
                                            expressionValue: "squeel"
                                        }
                                    ],
                                    nestedexpressions:
                                    [

                                    ]
                                },
                                {
                                    operator: "Or",
                                    expressions: [
                                        {
                                            filterField: "code",
                                            comparator: "doesnotcontain",
                                            expressionValue: "hoot hoot"
                                        },
                                        {
                                            filterField: "code",
                                            comparator: "contains",
                                            expressionValue: "stares with yellow eyes"
                                        }
                                    ],
                                    nestedexpressions:
                                    [

                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        };
 }])
.directive('conditionExpressionBuilder', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        templateUrl: 'conditionExpressionBuilder.html',
        scope: {
            conditions: "=",
            operators: "=",
            filterfields: "=",
            comparators: "="
        },
        controller: function($scope)
        {
             $scope.addNewCondition = function (arrayToPushInto) {
                var newCondition = { name: "testing" };
                arrayToPushInto.push(newCondition);
            };
            $scope.delete = function (expressionItem, expressionArray) {
                var index = expressionArray.indexOf(expressionItem);
                expressionArray.splice(index, 1);
            };
            $scope.removeNestedCondition = function (index, nestedExpressionArray) {
                nestedExpressionArray.splice(index, 1);     
            };
            $scope.addNestedCondition = function (nestedExpressionsArray) {
                var nestedConidtion = { operator: "", expressions: [{}], nestedexpressions: [{}] };
                nestedExpressionsArray.push(nestedConidtion);
            };
        }
    }
});
```